# How to replace consecutive and identical characters in Perl?

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I have a string like
`XXXXYYYYZZZYYZZZYYYY` which needs to be converted to
`XXXXAAAYZZZAYZZZAAAY`

`$s =~ s/Y{2}+/AY/g;`

this has 2 problems, `{2}+` will get YYYY to AYAY; and AY is not the same length as `YYYY` (expecting `AAAY`)

How to get this done in perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a "look-ahead":

```
$s =~ s/Y(?=Y+)/A/g;
```

`(?=Y+)` means "followed by one or more `Y` characters", so any `Y` character that is followed by another `Y` character will be replaced with an `A`.

[More info from `perlretut`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlretut.pod#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

Answer (score 4):

There's always more than one way to do it. My suggestion is to grab all the Ys except the last one, and then use that to create a string of As of the same length. The `e` modifier tells perl to execute the code in the replacement side instead of using it directly, and the `r` modifier tells `=~` to return the result of the substitution instead of modifying the input text directly (useful for these one-liner tests, among other places).

```
$ perl -E 'say shift =~ s/(Y+)(?=Y)/"A"x length$1/gre' XXXXYYYYZZZYYZZZYYYY
XXXXAAAYZZZAYZZZAAAY
```

Comment: That's not really the same - you moved the + to outside the capture, so the length is always 1, and your replacement will omit the ending Y(s), and it means more text is being matched and thus replaced. Yes, it can be made to work without the look-ahead, but I'd prefer it with.

Comment: my bad, yeah `(Y+)Y` than you can replace with length of captured group as `A` and one extra `Y`

Comment: Regexes: usually don't work on the first attempt. :) This is why I had to try three times to get the answer above to work :)

Answer (score 0):

`$s =~ s/Y{2}+/AY/g`
RHS Pattern is ambiguously obscure pattern: `Y{2}+`, that's very rarely used regex pattern except if `{}+` very rarely is available in few advanced regex engine, including perl maybe, as a regex feature called 'atomic grouping'.
You might have meant `(Y{2})+ which is (YY)+` or `Y{2,}` which is `YY+`
in perl it's no brainer simple and easy as it supports `lookaround` feature

```
perl -e '$s=XXXXYYYYZZZYYZZZYYYY ;$s =~ s/Y(?=Y)/A/g;print $s'
```

actually lower regex engine such sed still can do it albeit in cumbersome, uneasy way

```
echo XXXXYYYYZZZYYZZZYYYY |sed -E 's/YY+/&\n/g;s/Y/A/g;s/A\n/Y/g'
```